# Internet explorer 8 opens file in browser instead of the client

Tags: sharepoint-2007, internet-explorer-8, business-intelligence

Our company is working with a great Business Intelligence tool CorVu 4.2 to analyse the operational and strategic data. Since several years we are successfully working with Sharepoint 2007 to collaborate and share information with colleagues. Most of my colleagues are working with Internet Explorer 7, but step by step Internet Explorer 8 is implemented in the company.

We share a lot of CorVu files thought Sharepoint, but since we are using Internet Explorer 8, we have a problem that is new for us. If we click on a CorVu file in Internet Explorer 8 (not necessarily in Sharepoint) a pop-up shows how to open the file, if we save the file, there is no problem. But if we open the file, the file is shown in the browser and not in the CorVu client! See the screenshot below:

[image: inbrowsershot]
http://img169.imageshack.us/img169/5719/inbrowsershot.jpg

(I removed some unnecessary information)

So far my colleagues accept this 'feature' in Internet Explorer 8. But I we open and closes more CorVu files, multiple errors (more than 10) show up starting with:

(unable to place more hyperlinks)

By pressing Enter the errors disappear, but it's not professional! I contacted the creators of CorVu, but they don't have a solution for in their client. There may be a solution in Internet Explorer 8?

The extensions of a CorVu file can be a .sqy, .tab or .qrp. But is it possible to force the files to open in the standard client instead of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Add-Ons and see if you can disable the one that is displaying that content.

Tools -> Internet Options -> Programs -> Manage Add-ons

Your screenshot appears to be Excel.  You should be able to tweak Excel to remove the in-browser viewer.

Microsoft [discusses how to configure the Office-in-browser viewers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162059).  There are [methods for older computers](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000462.htm) as well.

If the browser is actually showing the CorVu program, then the CorVu program must have a plugin into IE when it was installed.  Try uninstalling IE and reinstalling it without touching CorVu.  That should purge all the custom stuff that CorVu did.

Comment: It seems to be Excel, but it's not. The screen is an in-browser view of the CorVu program. I tried to find an add-on, some of them I disabled, but none of them had any influence.
By the way, Excel files are opened in the MS Excel client and not in the browser.

Comment: Hmm, try uninstalling/reinstalling IE to get rid of the CorVu plugin.

Comment: We already tried to uninstall/reinstall IE8, but unfortunately without any effect.